# Delegate action without redirect in Play 1.2.x

Tags: java, redirect, playframework

Given a Play controller `MyController` with an action `myAction`, is it possible to call another action without triggering a redirect? Let's say I have another controller:

```
public class MyController2 extends Controller {
    public static void myAction2() throws Exception {
        MyController.myAction(); //this will cause a redirect.
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call `myAction` without triggering a redirect. **Note that I am using Play 1.2.x and not Play 2.x.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `myAction` and not have it redirect. Just change the access level of `myAction` to anything *except* `public`. However, you will not be able to route to `myAction` directly any more.

If you still need `myAction` to be routable in it's own right, then I would suggest moving any common functionality into a separate method/class and then calling that method from `myAction2` and `myAction`, like so:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void myAction() {
        commonActionStuff("myAction");
    }

    public static void myAction2() {
        commonActionStuff("myAction2");
    }

    protected static void commonActionStuff(String whoCalledMe) {

        // your common functionality implemented here

        renderText(whoCalledMe);
    }
}
```